# Multithreaded MD5 Hashing

Tags: c++, multithreading, hash, md5

I'm trying to multithread a program which take words from a file then hashes these and writes the results to another file.

If I make it without multithreading it's really fast, it's able to use only 15-20% of the CPU and has out like 300.000line/s

But when I tried with multithreading it only slow down and start to hash only at 17000lines/s, can you please help me?

Thanks

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout, std::streambuf, std::streamsize
#include <fstream>      // std::ifstream
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include "md5.h"

using namespace std;

static const int num_threads = 10;

void call_from_thread(int tid) {
    cout << "Launched by thread " << tid << std::endl;
    int cl = 0;
    int uscita = 0;
    int parole = 0;
    char* contents;
    ifstream istr("test.txt");

    if (istr) {
        streambuf * pbuf = istr.rdbuf();
        streamsize size = pbuf->pubseekoff(0, istr.end);
        pbuf->pubseekoff(0, istr.beg);       // rewind
        contents = new char[size];
        pbuf->sgetn(contents, size);
        istr.close();

        ofstream myfile;
        myfile.open("out.txt");

        do {
            string prova("");
            uscita = 0;
            do {
                if (contents[cl] == '\n') {
                    uscita = 1;
                }
                prova += contents[cl];
                cl += 1;
            } while (uscita != 1);
            parole += 1;
            //cout << prova << ":" << md5(prova) << endl;
            myfile << prova << ":" << md5(prova) << endl;
        } while (parole != 9586054);

        myfile.close();
    }
}

int main()
{

    thread t[num_threads];

    //Launch a group of threads
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i] = thread(call_from_thread, i);
    }

    cout << "Launched from the main\n";

    //Join the threads with the main thread
    for (int i = 0; i < num_threads; ++i) {
        t[i].join();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How many cpu cores do you have to run it on?...

Comment: You have ten thread all reading and seeking from the same file. If you're not using an SSD then the physical disk-heads have to move back and forth with each thread context switch. Try to read the full file into memory first, and then use the threads to do what they need from the in-memory buffer.

Comment: @Joe i run it on 48 Cores server

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i'm using SSDs

Comment: Also, why is each thread reading the processing the *whole* file? What is then the purpose of the threads if they all do the same work on the same data? Furthermore, each thread also write to the same output file, overwriting each others data.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude exactly the thing i want to avoid but i m not good with multithreading

Comment: For a possible solution to my latest comment, again you should probably read the whole file into memory (like you do now) but only *once*, before you start the threads. Then you divide the data into `num_threads` chunks, and have each thread only calculate the checksum of that chunk only. Save the output to memory and collate it later and write the result. ***However*** this only works if the lines are all the same length so the data could be split evenly. If each lines length varies you have to use some other algorithm to split the data into chunks.

Comment: Remember that there is execution overhead of creating and scheduling threads.  You may not see significant performance improvement using threads here because the OS needs to schedule execution of the threads on one or more cores (along with all the other tasks running).  The multi-thread solution is to have one thread reading the data, while another thread performs the calculations on the data.  You may want give the reader thread a head start since reading a file is slower than calculating from memory.

Answer (score 0):

What you see here is that all the threads are reading the same file and doing the same work. This results in that the file has to be read `num_threads` times, probably causing a slowdown of about `num_threads` (since file I/O probably is on the critical path) or maybe even more because of more cache misses.

You could try reading the entire file into memory, splitting it up between your threads and then having each thread process a subset of that files content.